# Scrolling tableview changes cell content

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

1. I'm loading two tableViews separately one after the other in a same view (ScrollView).But after loading them when I try to scroll the first tableView then its cell(1st and last) contents are changed to second tableViews cell(1st and last) content.Couldn't understand where I m going wrong?

This is the code Im working on:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
      self.tableView1=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,310,250) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
        self.tableView1.delegate=self;
        self.tableView1.dataSource=self;
        self.tableView1.rowHeight=80;
        self.tableView1.scrollEnabled = YES;
        currenttableView=@"1";
        [testscroll addSubview:self.tableView1];
 [self performSelector:@selector(callWebserviceMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
}
-(void)callWebserviceMethod
{
  self.tableView2=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,self.tableView1.frame.origin.y+self.tableView1.frame.size.height+6,310,230) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
        self.tableView2.delegate=self;
        self.tableView2.dataSource=self;
        self.tableView2.rowHeight=80;
         currenttableView=@"2";
        self.tableView2.scrollEnabled = YES;
        [testscroll addSubview:self.tableView2];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";

    UITableViewCell* cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault    reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];

    }
    cell.accessoryType= UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


    if(currenttableView==@"1")
    {


        cell.textLabel.text = [[filtered objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"CompanyName"] ;   //filtered is NSMutableArray
        cell.textLabel.tag=3;
        cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];


        UIButton *showDirections = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        showDirections.frame = CGRectMake(10.0f, 52.0f, 85.0f, 20.0f);
        [showDirections setTitle:@"Direction" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [showDirections setTag:indexPath.row];
        [showDirections.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12]];
        showDirections.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightTextColor];
        [ showDirections setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background-button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        showDirections.titleLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

        [cell addSubview:showDirections];
        [showDirections addTarget:self action:@selector(showDirectionsfordC:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



        return cell;

    }


     if(currenttableView==@"2")
    {


        cell.textLabel.text = [[places objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"] ;    //places is NSMutableArray
        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines=0;
        cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
        cell.textLabel.tag=3;




        UIButton *showDirections = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        showDirections.frame = CGRectMake(10.0f, 52.0f, 85.0f, 20.0f);
        [showDirections setTitle:@"Direction" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [showDirections setTag:indexPath.row];
        [showDirections.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12]];
        showDirections.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightTextColor];
        [ showDirections setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background-button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        showDirections.titleLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

        [cell addSubview:showDirections];
        [showDirections addTarget:self action:@selector(showDirections:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        NSString *vicinity1 = [[places objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"vicinity"];
        UILabel *vicinity = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 45, 320, 10)];
        vicinity .font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT" size:12];
        [vicinity  setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
        vicinity.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",vicinity1];

        vicinity.tag=4;
        [cell addSubview:vicinity ];
        vicinity.hidden=YES;
        [vicinity release];

        return cell;



    }

    }
```

Where I m going wrong?

2.. When tableView2 is empty then ScrollView loads with only tableView1.Then at that time when I try to scroll tableView1 then I m getting error :`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'` 
at this line of tableView2

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[places objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"] ;//error
```

How can I get it going?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as par your First point you need to your `CellIdentifier` replace with

```
  NSString *CellIdentifier =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];
```

and

```
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

and second point Error says you have  set `cell.textLabel.text` from placesArray that have no any Data or key like `name` at any index  your Array is Nil that's why your app Getting Crash while scrolling

Comment: For the first issue when I try ur code the issue continues the same.Eventhough cell contents are changed.Any thing else should I modify?

Comment: put this if conditon currenttableView=1 or other if into if(cell == nil){}

Comment: When I try to scroll the tableView1 jumps to - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ and  if(currenttableView==@"2").How can I recognise which tableView is getting scrolled ?

Comment: you can recognize with this if conditio if (tableView == yourTableOutlateName){}

Comment: Nitin solved partially ie cell's content text is not getting changed.I got it.As u can see from my code I have UIButtons created in my tableView1 and tableView2.So as I begin to scroll either of the tableView's buttons text colour is changed from white to black.How can i solve it ?

Comment: @Nitin thank you very much for your answer, i've been having this problem since last night, and it was driving me nuts!!!! Now i can finally proceed on doing something else, thank you again!!